# Grails Immediate commit for objects in a transaction

Tags: mysql, grails, transactions

In my project there is a table called `process_detail`. Row inserted in this table as soon as a cron process starts and is updated at the end
of the cron process completion. We are using grails which internally takes care of transaction at service level method i.e. transaction starts at the start of the method, commit if the method execution successful, rollback if any exception.
Here what happens is that if the transaction fails this row also being rolled back this I don't want because this is type of a log 
table. I tried creating a nested transaction and save this row and at the end update it but that fails with lock acquisition exception.

I am thinking of using MyISAM for this particular table, 
this way I don't have to worry about transaction because MyISAM does not support it and it will commit immediately and no rollback possible. Here's pseudo code for what I am trying to achieve.

```
def someProcess(){
  //Transaction starts
  saveProcessDetail(details); //Commit this immediately, should not rollback if below code fails.
  someOtherWork;
  updateProcessDetail(details); //Commit this immediately, should
  //Transaction Ends
}
```

Pseudo code for save and update process detail;

```
def saveProcessDetail(processName, processStatus){
  ProcessDetail pd = new ProcessDetail(processName, processStatus);
  pd.save();
}

def updateProcessDetail(processDetail, processStatus){
  pd.procesStatus = processStatus;
  pd.save();
}
```

Please advice if there is better of doing this in InnoDB. Answer could be mysql level I can find the grails solution my self. Let me know if any other info required.

Comment: You need to show `saveProcessDetail()` method, in order for us to suggest something.

Comment: @AdeelAnsari : Added, I have used them as method they might as well be just two lines of code which create `ProcessDetail` object and saves it.

Answer (score 0):

Make someProcess @NonTransactional, then manage the transactional nature yourself.  Write the initial saveProcessDetail with a flush:true, then make the remainder of the processing transactional, withTransaction?

Or

```
@NonTransactional 
def someProcess() {
    saveProcessDetail(details) // I'd still use a flush:true
    transactionalProcessWork()
}

@Transactional
def transactionalProcessWork() {
    someOtherWork()
    updateProcessDetail(details)
}
```

Comment: This looks like it could work. I will give it a try.

Comment: Using flush true is not a good practice, cause you are breaking the transaction. I would try without it

Comment: @quindimildev, you're not breaking it, you're completing it.